# Bind two inputs so they display the same text even if one of them was changed using only native JS

Tags: javascript, html

I know how do that with Jquery http://jsfiddle.net/69UAT/ But can you help me with native JS.
jQuery:

```
$('.inputs').on('keyup',function(){
    $(this).parent().not(this).find('.inputs').val($(this).val());
}
);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="inputs" value="hello">
    <input type="text" class="inputs" value="John">
</div>
```

Comment: please describe what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I only want to bind two input fields like here http://jsfiddle.net/69UAT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".inputs");
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    let value = e.target.value;
    inputs.forEach(input => input.value = value);
  });
});
```